# Using TDA2003 as a typical op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio

I used a [TDA2003](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/DM00028077.pdf) to make a simple audio amplifier using a circuit I found online and it worked.

Then I was wondering, since the TDA2003 as far as I understand is an op-amp, why can't I use it this way:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy04JF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For both R1 and Rf I used 330Ω resistors so the gain should be:

```
(330+330)/330 = 2
```

All I got is noise when I connected the speaker, even without an input connected.

In the end what I am trying to achieve is something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbfeI7.png)</sup>

Is this possible?

Comment: It ain't an op amp.

Comment: pinout of tda2003 shows that pin 1 is the non inverting input and pin 2 is the inverting input. Doesn't that mean that it is an op amp?

Comment: A chip is an opamp when it has the characteristics of an opamp. This chip doesn't. And the fact that the word "opamp" or something similar doesn't appear in the datasheet is a big hint.

Comment: Even a 741, invented in neolithic age, is way better than this one in terms of opamp performance. Trust me.

Answer (score 4):

The TDA2003 is not an operational amplifier. Typical structure of input stage of OPA is a symmetrical differential circuit, which is flexible and symmetrical in terms of biasing relative to ground.

If you examine the [TDA2003 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00028077.pdf), you will see that pins 1 and 2 are simply taps to an emitter follower: one to its base, and the other to its emitter. To operate, these pins must be DC decoupled, as all application diagrams suggest. Connecting TDA2003 pins as instrumental OPA will bias all internals and won't work as you expected.

Comment: I tried the bridged circuit from one of the tda2003's datasheets I found online and I still get noise when I connect the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

Years ago, I did the same thing, thinking the 2003 could be strapped like an opamp. I tried it and got the same results--noise. it just didn't work. The 2003 is simply a different animal; they simply weren't made to work that way. However, the tda2005 will work as an opamp--cause it is! It's a power opamp. I'd recommend using the tda2005, tda2020, lm1875. These all use the to220-5 package similar to the 2003, but they're true opmps and can be used on single or split supply rails.

Answer (score 1):

TDA2003 is not really an op-amp, as can be seen by comparing its datasheet with the one, say, for LM741

- Voltage gain: 40dB (100x) for TDA2003 vs 50 V/mV (50_000x) for LM741
- Input resistance: 150K (TDA2003) vs 2000K (LM741)

As you can see, it makes horrible op-amp. Moreover, using TDA2003 as input buffer is very wasteful -- why use big, noisy and expensive chips when you only need a tiny fraction of their output power?

Comment: I tried the bridged circuit from one of the tda2003's datasheets I found online and I still get noise when I connect the speaker.

Comment: Ok? That means that you made a mistake assembling a circuit or that your chips are burned out. In any case, this is a separate question -- if you need help with that, do not ask it in the comments, start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Too far from OPAMP. Single transistor in the input.
[image]

See the DC bias voltages:
[image]